# How to close Primeng growl all messages if one was closed?

Tags: angular, primeng

[CLICK on Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj0Fp.jpg)

The growl messages life is 5000, if I close one message the others not closing automatically after 5 seconds

Comment: Please embed your image - it will be easier for people to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a wrapper for primeng growl messages called primeng-advanced-growl (https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng-advanced-growl). With the help of this wrapper you should be able to achieve the desired behaviour.